# IBM Quest Data Generator parameters for transaction generation

Tags: hadoop, dataset, generator

I need to generate synthetic datasets for association rule mining to compare the performance of my algorithm with the existing ones. I downloaded IBM Quest Data generator, but don't know how to generate datasets with the same parameters used in the papers. For example, how to generate T40I10D100K.dat T40I10D1000K.dat, T10I4D100K.dat T25I10D10k.data datasets? What does T, I and D mean and how to set these parameters when using the generator?

Help outputs the following.

```
hduser@master:~$ ./gen lit -help 
Command Line Options:
-ntrans number_of_transactions (in 1000's) (default: 1000)
  -tlen avg_items_per_transaction (default: 10)
  -nitems number_of_different_items (in '000s) (default: 100000)
  -npats number_of_patterns (default: 10000)
  -patlen avg_length_of_maximal_pattern (default: 4)
  -corr correlation_between_patterns (default: 0.25)
  -conf avg_confidence_in_a_rule (default: 0.75)
  -fname <filename> (write to filename.data and filename.pat)
  -ascii (default: False)

  -randseed # (reset seed used generate to x-acts; must be negative)
  -version (to print out version info)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the IBM generator here:

http://forum.ai-directory.com/read.php?5,33

And here is the explanation of the letters:

D: number of sequences in the dataset
C: average number of itemsets per sequence
T: average number of items per itemset
S: average number of itemsets in potentially frequent sequences.
I: average size of itemsets in potentially frequent sequences
N: number of different items in the dataset